# Uniformly Bounded in a Schauder Norm

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, holder-spaces, functional-inequalities

Suppose $\{h_{k}\}$ is a sequence of elements in $C^{2,\alpha}$.

I want to show that $\{h_{k}\}$ is uniformly bounded in $C^{2,\alpha}$.

Now, if I'm not mistaken, then $$||h_{k}||_{\displaystyle C^{2,\alpha}} = ||h_{k}||_{\infty} + ||D(h_{k})||_{\infty} + ||D^{2}(h_{k})||_{\infty}+ \sup \left\{ \displaystyle \frac{|h_{k}(x)-h_{k}(y)|}{|x-y|^{\alpha}} \right\} +\\+\sup \left\{ \displaystyle \frac{|D(h_{k}(x))-D(h_{k}(y))|}{|x-y|^{\alpha}} \right\} + \sup \left\{ \displaystyle \frac{|D^{2}(h_{k}(x))-D^{2}(h_{k}(y))|}{|x-y|^{\alpha}} \right\}.$$

So, in order to show that $||h_{k}||_{\displaystyle C^{2,\alpha}} \leq C$, I need to show that each of these summands is $\leq C$.

I'm thinking that the last three terms with $\sup$ in them might be uniformly bounded just by nature of their being $\sup$s.  The other ones, I might be able to bound by some other $L_{p}$ norm, if there is any relationship between an $L_{\infty}$ norm and an $L_{2}$ norm, say.

Could somebody please tell me if there is any kind of less than or equal relationship between these norms; i.e., any inequalities that express a relationship between them.

Comment: I don't think you want 4th and 5th terms of your definition of $||\cdot||_{C^{2,\alpha}}$.  What you're trying to prove, as written, is false:  e.g. take $h_k=k$ (Constant function with value k).

Comment: @mathematician, then what is the correct definition of $|| \cdot || _{C^{2,\alpha}}$?

Comment: It's supposed to be the sum of the derivatives of $||h||_{\infty} + \sup_{x \neq y} \frac{|h(x) - h(y)|}{|x-y|^{\alpha}}$ up to order 2, isn't it?

Comment: As I said, just get rid of the 4th and 5th terms.  You only put the thing with the $\alpha$ on the highest order derivatives.  And my comment that what you're trying to prove is false is independent of what the particular norm is.  You must be missing some conditions on the sequence that you're trying to prove is uniformly bounded.

Comment: @mathematician, I wound up taking a different approach. But, thank you so much for all your help and valuable insights! :)